# break a long table over pages while imposing a table line on each page

Tags: tables, longtable

I want to draw a big table that goes over three of four pages. I understand package longtable is the most appropriate in this case. My table is a simple table, two columns: symbols and signification. I want the table to display the first line (symbol and signification) on **each** page at the beginnning (i.e. i want latex to understand to put that first line whenever the page ends). How do I do that? (See picture)
Thanks,
Eric.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the documentation, especially section *3 Heading* `\endhead` and such. [Here on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) or use the commandline on your computer (or terminal) and write `texdoc longtable`.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a matter of placing the `\endhead`. This is easily found in the documentation for `longtable`, under section 3.

In this example I have used some looping just to simulate a long table, as you did not include a Minimal Working Example.

Also, I've used the `booktabs`, which gives a much nicer look to tables.

**Output**

Image taken for page two, but every page will have the same header.

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcounter{loopcounter}
\newcounter{numofrows}
\setcounter{numofrows}{50}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
\toprule
Awesome headertext & Equally awesome headertext\\
\midrule
\endhead
  \forloop{loopcounter}{1}{\value{loopcounter} < \numexpr\value{numofrows}}{%
    \number\value{loopcounter} & \tabularnewline}%
    \number\value{loopcounter} & \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\endhead` was the solution, the problem is resolved.